# Replacing by tab character in Sed in Osx

Tags: linux, sed, osx

I am working in Mac OS X,I have tried several commands in sed to replace by a tab character followed by a file name.

```
for f in *.txt; do sed -i '' -e "s/$/\t$f/g" $f; done


for f in *.txt; do sed -i '' -e "s/$/[CTR+V][CTR+I]$f/g" $f; done
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363328/replacing-with-tab-using-sed)

But I get a t character instead of a tab.
Any suggestions to modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```sh
for f in ./*.txt; do
  sed -i '' -e "s/$/$(printf '\t')$f/g" "$f"
done
```

Comment: What is `sed -i '' -e ...` for?

Comment: @mikeserv: `OSX sed` require `-i ''` for replacing in-place without backup extension.

Comment: Oh. Man, `-i` is really a terrible switch anyway - I wish more people understood that. Thanks, cuonglm.